# Find primitive function of $x^{\alpha} \cdot \cos(x), \quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've tried to find a primitive function for this integral and not been successful.

I've tried integration by parts but I just don't end up in a useful primitive function to evaluate.

$$\int_{l}^{u}{x^{\alpha}\cdot \cos{x}}\,dx, \alpha \in R, \alpha \notin N$$

My solution so far where I have removed the upper and lower limits and only try to find the primitive function:

$$\int{x^{\alpha}\cdot \cos{x}}\,dx \iff \frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1} \cdot \cos{x} + \int{\frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1}\cdot \sin{x}\,dx} \iff$$
$$\iff \frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1}\cdot \cos{x} + \frac{x^{\alpha + 2}}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)}\cdot \sin{x} - \int{\frac{x^{\alpha + 2}}{(\alpha + 2)(\alpha + 1)}\cdot \cos{x}\,dx}$$
Now this really does not help me since moving the integral on the right hand side to the left hand side will yield
$$
\int{(x^{\alpha} + \frac{x^{\alpha + 2}}{(\alpha + 2)(\alpha + 1)})\cdot \cos{x}\,dx} = \frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1}\cdot \cos{x} + \frac{x^{\alpha + 2}}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)}\cdot \sin{x} \iff
$$
$$
\iff
\int{x^{\alpha}(1 + \frac{x^2}{(\alpha + 2)(\alpha + 1)})\cdot \cos{x}\,dx} = \frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1}\cdot \cos{x} + \frac{x^{\alpha + 2}}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)}\cdot \sin{x}
$$
So I don't have a constant on the left side, as these problems we get usually end up with and I'm stuck.

Does anyone know what trick I should use to find the primitive function of this integral?

Is there anything wrong with my application here?

**Edit**:
This is the closest I get to rewriting the integral in a "simpler" form (we almost have $z \cos{z}$ but it's not there):

$$\int_l^u x^{\alpha}\cos{x}\,dx = \begin{bmatrix}x=y^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}&x=l \iff y=l^\alpha\\\,dx=\,\frac{1}{\alpha}y^{\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}}dy&x=u \iff y=u^\alpha\end{bmatrix} = \\ \int_{l^\alpha}^{u^\alpha}y \cos{y^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha}y^{\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}}\,dy = 
\int_{l^\alpha}^{u^\alpha}y^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\cos{y^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\,dy$$

Comment: Your method gets $I(\alpha+2)$ in terms of $I(\alpha)$.  Then for $\alpha$ a positive integer, we inductively only need to know $I(0), I(1)$, which are well-known.  For $\alpha$ not a nonnegative integer, this integral is not elementary.

Comment: ok, but $\alpha$ is not allowed to be an integer (same story anyway, right?)

Comment: Induction cannot be used in that case...as $\alpha$ is not a natural number..

Comment: Maple gets this in terms of some ${}_1F_2$ hypergeometric functions.

Comment: How do you see the I($\alpha$ + 2)? I can understand it since I get a raised "polynomial" by 2 but it's not the same function.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution in elementary functions..

Comment: ok thanks... I have to check what they meant with this assignment then.

Comment: factor out the constant $1/((\alpha+2)(\alpha+1))$.

Comment: But if $\alpha$ is a natural number...then yes..the problem can be solved using induction

Answer (score 1):

My answer is regarding the indefinite integral
$$\int{x^a\cos(x)dx}$$
There is no solution in elementary functions, but just in case you wanna know, wolfram alpha gives
$$\int{x^a\cos(x)dx}=\frac{1}{2}ix^a(x^2)^{-a}((-ix)^{a}\Gamma(a+1,ix)-(ix)^a\Gamma(a+1,-ix))+C$$
where $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function

More info about the gamma function can be found here (source Wikipedia) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: Thanks for the hint :-) I'll have a look at it

Comment: Thanks for posting your question!